# Is there any way to get the values of local variables (like sosex !mdv) with ClrMD?

Tags: c#, windbg, sos, sosex, clrmd

Using windbg with SOS and SOSEX, I can use the !mdv command which "Displays arguments and locals for a managed frame". Is there any way to achieve the same results programmatically with [ClrMD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've synced with the dev who owns CLR MD. We currently don't have support for locals, but we plan on providing it at some point.

To set expectations, we're thinking of providing a fidelity similar to `!clrstack` but not as detailed as `ICorDebug`.